# вставка изображения из модуля Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть модуль, к примеру называется arenda, там создал папку web, далее папку images и хочу там хранить все картинки этого модуля но столкнулся с проблемой что в стилях не могу достучаться до картинки, так как насколько я понимаю папка закрыта для чтения из вне. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Можно попробовать создать символическую ссылку `ln -s` с папки модуля в публичную папку `web`

Comment: Можешь подробнее описать как это сделать или ссылку на материал?

Comment: [ln - s](http://tftf.ru/stati/linux/sozdat_simvolicheskuyu_ssylku_na_papku_fajl/)
Если не получится создать ссылку то напиши путь к публичной папке и путь к папке с картинками в модуле. Я помогу

Comment: @Анатолий я вот так делал ссылки на винде:
`c:\>mklink /j "c:\openserver\domains\poll.ua\frontend\web\upload\cache" "c:\openserver\domains\poll.ua\backend\web\upload\cache"`. Сначала куда ведет ссылка, потом откуда.
А для линукса вроде бы вот так будет:
`ln -s c:/openserver/domains/poll.ua/backend/web/upload/cache/ c:/openserver/domains/poll.ua/frontend/web/upload/cache/ `